# Dash multipage "stored component" values

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to implement a multipage Dash webapp and I am having a hard time to "store" changes in components when switching back and forth across pages. Namely, each time I move to a new page, the layout is refreshed.

Below there is a (minimal?) code example for reproducibility purpose, where in Page 1 there is a html table with the first row allowing for user input and add button, then it is possible to remove the inserted row as well.
Page 2 is just a placeholder for switching back and forth.

I guess one strategy could be to have different `dcc.Store`s and record what happens, and populate pages from that when switching. But I hope there is a better strategy tbh :)

**index.py**

```py
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# Dash app
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    external_stylesheets=[
        dbc.themes.FLATLY,
        dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP,
    ],
    use_pages=True,
)

sidebar = dbc.Col(
    id="sidebar",
    children=[
        dbc.Nav(
            id="sidebar-nav",
            children=[
                dbc.NavLink(children="page1", id="page1", href="/page1", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink(children="page2", id="page2", href="/page2", active="exact")
            ],
        ),
    ],
)

main_content = dbc.Col(
    id="main-content",
    className="main-content-expanded",
    children=dash.page_container,
)

page = dbc.Row(
    id="page",
    children=[
        sidebar,
        main_content,
    ],
)

url = dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False)

# App layout
app.layout = html.Div(
    id="layout",
    children=[page, url],
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run_server(
        debug=True,
        host=0.0.0.0,
        port=8080,
    )
```

**pages/page1.py**

```py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import MATCH, Input, Output, Patch, State, callback, html, dcc
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate


dash.register_page(__name__, path="/page1", name="Page1")


def make_filled_row(button_clicked: int, name: str) -> html.Tr:
    """
    Creates a filled row in the table, with dynamic id using the button_clicked
    parameter.
    """
    return html.Tr(
        [
            html.Td(name),
            html.Td(
                html.Button(
                    "Delete",
                    id={"index": button_clicked, "type": "delete"},
                    className="delete-user-btn",
                )
            ),
        ],
        id={"index": button_clicked, "type": "table-row"},
    )


header = [
    html.Thead(
        html.Tr(
            [
                html.Th("First Name"),
                html.Th(""),
            ]
        ),
        id="table-header",
    )
]


add_row = html.Tr([
    html.Td(dcc.Input(id="name-input")),
    html.Td(html.Button("Add", id="add-user-btn",)),
])

body = [html.Tbody([add_row], id="table-body")]

table = html.Table(header + body)


# Layout of the page
layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([dbc.Col([table])]),
])

# List of callbacks for the page
@callback(
    Output("table-body", "children", allow_duplicate=True),
    Output("name-input", "value"),
    Input("add-user-btn", "n_clicks"),
    State("name-input", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def on_add(n_clicks: int, name: str):
    """Adds a new row to the table, and clears the input fields"""
    table_body = Patch()
    table_body.append(make_filled_row(n_clicks, name))

    return table_body, ""


@callback(
    Output({"index": MATCH, "type": "table-row"}, "children"),
    Input({"index": MATCH, "type": "delete"}, "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def on_delete(n_clicks: int) -> html.Tr:
    """Deletes the row from the table"""
    if not n_clicks:
        raise PreventUpdate

    return html.Tr([])
```

**pages/page2.py**

```py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html
dash.register_page(__name__, path="/page2", name="Page2")

# Layout of the page
layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([dbc.Col(html.Div("You are on page 2"))]),
])
```

Comment: This is the main problem I have with multi pages in dash currently. Some dcc components have a `persistence` option, but that can't be applied in this example. One approach that works is hiding/showing pages instead of rerendering them https://community.plotly.com/t/retain-page-state-in-multi-page-apps-when-visiting-other-pages/11532, but it has its downsides. So if that doesn't work for you then using a Store is probably still the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That is interesting but basically solves the problem by not using dash pages at all, and it is a solution I used in the past. Looks like we are in a very similar situation. I tried to "persist" what I could, but html element do not give you such power. I have a fallback solution using dcc.Store, but it leads to in page actions to be much slower.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. I ended up not using pages at all anymore and replace them with dbc.Tabs.

Comment: @gdevaux That may work for simple apps, but tabs are very different from paths, and you cannot do anything too complex with them. Example: [variable paths](https://dash.plotly.com/urls#variable-paths)

Comment: @FBruzzesi see this [link](https://github.com/AnnMarieW/dash-multi-page-app-demos/tree/main/multi_page_store)

Comment: @HamidRasti thank you for commenting. I am aware of such repo, with many useful resources. Yet in this case tables do not have a `persistence` parameter which is what the author there is using for her dropdown component

Comment: @FBruzzesi FYI I have added a solution to consider for this if still interested/seeking one

Answer (score 1):

## You can have fast data persistence via `dcc.Store` across multiple pages (i.e., URLs) within one `app.py` script

There should not be any issues with latency in any app context where what is being preserved are UI changes via component user interactions. At any rate, still, with any relevant application, there should not be any noticeable effects on the app's responsiveness/ 'reactivity' using an approach like the following.

For example:

```py
import dash
from dash import ALL, Dash, Input, Output, State
from dash import ctx, dcc, html

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


app = Dash(
    __name__,
    suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.FLATLY],
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
        dcc.Link("Navigate to Page 1", href="/page-1"),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Link("Navigate to Page 2", href="/page-2"),
        dcc.Store(id="store-table-data", storage_type="session"),
        html.Div(id="page-content"),
    ],
    style={"margin": "20%", "textAlign": "center"},
)

# Layout for page 1
page_1_layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Page 1"),
        html.Table(
            [
                html.Thead([html.Tr([html.Th("Name"), html.Th("Action")])]),
                html.Tbody(id="table-body"),
            ]
        ),
        dcc.Input(id="name-input", type="text", placeholder="Enter name"),
        html.Button("Add Row", id="add-row-button"),
    ]
)

# Layout for page 2
page_2_layout = html.Div([html.H1("Page 2")])


@app.callback(
    Output("page-content", "children"),
    [Input("url", "pathname")],
    [State("store-table-data", "data")],
)
def display_page(pathname, stored_data):
    if pathname == "/page-1":
        return page_1_layout
    elif pathname == "/page-2":
        return page_2_layout
    else:
        return "404"


@app.callback(
    Output("table-body", "children"),
    Output("store-table-data", "data"),
    [
        Input("add-row-button", "n_clicks"),
        Input({"type": "delete-button", "index": ALL}, "n_clicks"),
    ],
    [State("name-input", "value"), State("store-table-data", "data")],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_table(add_n_clicks, delete_n_clicks, input_value, stored_data):

    if stored_data is None:
        stored_data = []

    # Handle add action
    if ctx.triggered_id == "add-row-button" and input_value:
        stored_data.append(input_value)
    # Handle delete actions
    else:
        try:
            deleted = stored_data[ctx.triggered_id["index"]]
            del stored_data[ctx.triggered_id["index"]]
            print(f"Deleted {deleted}")
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    rows = []
    for i, name in enumerate(stored_data):
        row = html.Tr(
            [
                html.Td(name),
                html.Td(
                    html.Button(
                        "Delete", id={"type": "delete-button", "index": i}
                    )
                ),
            ]
        )
        rows.append(row)

    return rows, stored_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

produces the following demonstrated data persistence (where I've opened Chrome devtools to watch the changes in state of the local browser cache storage [for which I've chosen the 'session' type - meaning it persists so long as the same tab exists, even if reloaded; however, any new tab will create a new 'session']):

[image: Recorded video screen shot of dash app]

Answer (score 0):

It is a good approach to use a global `dcc.Store` to store your pages data:

#### *index.py*

Just add the store:

```py
# App layout
app.layout = html.Div(
    id="layout",
    children=[
        # add this:
        dcc.Store(
            id='store',
            storage_type='local',
            data={},
        ),
        page,
        url,
    ],
)
```

#### *page1.py*

A working method to store data `on_add`

```py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import MATCH, Input, Output, Patch, State, callback, html, dcc
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

dash.register_page(__name__, path="/page1", name="Page1")


def make_filled_row(button_clicked: int, name: str) -> html.Tr:
    """
    Creates a filled row in the table, with dynamic id using the button_clicked
    parameter.
    """
    if not button_clicked:
        raise PreventUpdate
    return html.Tr(
        [
            html.Td(name),
            html.Td(
                html.Button(
                    "Delete",
                    id={"index": button_clicked, "type": "delete"},
                    className="delete-user-btn",
                )
            ),
        ],
        id={"index": button_clicked, "type": "table-row"},
    )


header = [
    html.Thead(
        html.Tr(
            [
                html.Th("First Name"),
                html.Th(""),
            ]
        ),
        id="table-header",
    )
]

add_row = html.Tr([
    html.Td(dcc.Input(id="name-input")),
    html.Td(html.Button("Add", id="add-user-btn", )),
])

body = [html.Tbody([add_row], id="table-body")]

table = html.Table(header + body)

# Layout of the page
layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([dbc.Col([table])]),
])


# List of callbacks for the page
@callback(
    # Output("table-body", "children", allow_duplicate=True),
    Output("store", "data"),
    Output("name-input", "value"),
    Input("add-user-btn", "n_clicks"),
    State("name-input", "value"),
    State("store", "data"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def on_add(n_clicks: int, name: str, store: dict):
    """Adds a new row to the store, and clears the input fields"""

    if not n_clicks:
        raise PreventUpdate

    store = {
        'data': [*store.get('data', []), name]
    }

    return store, ""


@callback(
    Output({"index": MATCH, "type": "table-row"}, "children"),
    Input({"index": MATCH, "type": "delete"}, "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def on_delete(n_clicks: int) -> html.Tr:
    """Deletes the row from the table"""
    if not n_clicks:
        raise PreventUpdate

    return html.Tr([])


@callback(
    Output("table-body", "children"),
    Input('store', 'modified_timestamp'),
    State('store', 'data'),
)
def on_data(ts, store):
    if ts is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    table_body = Patch()
    table_body.clear()
    table_body.append(html.Tr([
        html.Td(dcc.Input(id="name-input")),
        html.Td(html.Button("Add", id="add-user-btn", )),
    ]))

    for i, name in enumerate(store.get("data", [])):
        table_body.append(make_filled_row(i + 1, name))

    return table_body
```

You can use the same method to delete item from the store when `on_delete` callback triggered.

Comment: @FBruzzesi was it helpful?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me try to articulate my thoughts here.
I currently have a solution in place using `dcc.Store`. Everything runs smoothly within the same page. However when switching from page2 back to page1, then for some reason, what you called `on_data` callback would not trigger directly if using pages. Therefore I add a fake callback in the middle, but this solution slows down the table creation to a level that it is very humanly noticeable. You can read an example I made on the [dash forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/multipage-stored-components/74657)

Comment: Of course I can avoid using pages, but I thought to have a nice use case for them. Its usage simplifies some other manual logic handling.